# How to send HTTPS request with certificates in java

Tags: ssl, post, https, certificate, using

I need to convert following curl command to JAVA code. to send HTTPS request with certificate,

curl https://connect2.pointclickcare.com/api/public/preview1/orgs/6a69f753-1353-4def-a428-e42e1206b90b/facs -H "Authorization: Bearer H6B2nrdEA9KuW6jrW3gOLJU5KwUd:2" --cert fullchain21.pem --key privkey21.pem